# Function is not calling the correct function

Tags: javascript

I want to save a bool value for when you refresh the page, the value is true (if you want the color theme to be default, white) and false (if you want the color theme to be dark, black). Local storage is saving the last value correctly, and loading the correct value, but it is still not working, I don't know why. Here is my code, any help would be grateful.

```
var link = document.getElementById("color-mode");
var button = document.getElementById("theme-button");
var searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");
var userSettings = document.getElementById("user-settings");
var siteLogo = document.getElementById("site-logo");
var isDefault = false;

button.onclick = function() {
    if(isDefault == true) {
        DarkTheme();
    }
    else {
        DefaultTheme();
    }
}

function DefaultTheme() {
    link.href = "../static/CSS/default.css";
    isDefault = true;
    searchButton.src = "../static/Media/SearchIconDefault.png";
    userSettings.src = "../static/Media/UserIconDefault.png";
    siteLogo.src = "../static/Media/LogoDefault.png";
    window.localStorage.setItem("saveTheme", isDefault);
}

function DarkTheme() {
    link.href = "../static/CSS/dark.css";
    isDefault = false;
    searchButton.src = "../static/Media/SearchIconDark.png";
    userSettings.src = "../static/Media/UserIconDark.png";
    siteLogo.src = "../static/Media/LogoDark.png";
    window.localStorage.setItem("saveTheme", isDefault);
}

function load() {
    isDefault = window.localStorage.getItem("saveTheme");
    console.log("Val: " + isDefault);
    if(isDefault == false) {
        DarkTheme();
    }
    else {
        DefaultTheme();
    }
}

load();
```

Comment: Not necessarily related, but `console.log("Val: " + isDefault);` forces `isDefault` to be cast to string. That isn't helpful when you want to debug. Try e.g. `console.log("Val:", isDefault);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your code:

1. `load()` initially had `isDefault` as `false`
2. it calls `DarkTheme`, which sets `isDefault` also to `false`
3. then user click button
4. `isDefault` is false - then `DarkTheme` is called, which test `isDefault` also to `false`.

Application basically can't enter other theme, except the case where you change something manually in localStorage.

Change code to :

```js
button.onclick = function() {
    if(isDefault == true) {
        DefaultTheme();
    }
    else {
        DarkTheme();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it was helpful, but it is no longer saving, I don't know why, but thanks anyway.